# Switch Jenkins Slave to a Different Master

Tags: jenkins

I have a simple Jenkins master/slave set-up but I'd like to be able to switch which master the slave points at.

Is it possible to do this by changing some config on the slave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Windows Slave configuration remove the JNLP Slave for Master1/Slave node by
    1. Stopping the Jenkins Slave Windows service
    2. Launch a Command Prompt as an Administrator
    3. then use ***sc delete jenkins_service_name***

For OS X check out https://github.com/rhwood/jenkins-slave-osx/wiki/Uninstall

Now open a browser on the slave machine and go to your Jenkins master2 server url then Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> Node (assuming the node is already setup on master2 server) and click on the Launch button to launch agent from browser on slave machine. You prob. know how to do this already. If not use this guide https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Maybe you can try having the slave setup on both master1 and master2 by
1. Skip my delete steps above
2. open a browser on the slave machine and go to your Jenkins master2 server url then Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> Node (assuming the node is already setup on master2 server) and click on the Launch button to launch agent from browser on slave machine.
3. Instead do "Save File" and click ok in step **5b** from https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines
4. Save the ***slave-agent.jnlp*** to a new folder. I'm sure the two agents will run on that slave machine without interfering each other.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. If you want to be able to switch the slave back and forth between two masters, you can set up a second slave agent on the slave machine. Steps to do this depend on the type of slave (JNLP, remote ssh, etc). Disconnect the slave from the old master using the Manage Slaves page, and shut down the first slave agent on the slave machine. Start your second slave agent, and add that slave to the second master.

You can actually have both slave agents running and have the slave be connected to both masters, although they won't know anything about each other and could both send a job to the slave at the same time regardless of the number of executors.